# onKeyUp not returning true

Tags: android

I am trying to return true value from onKeyUp-method but in the mobile device, I still have volume-toolbar showing when I press volume-up Button.
I am using Android 8.
What is the problem?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        VolDown();


    return true; //// still showing volume-toolbar when pressing volume-up

}
```

build Gradle Module.app

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "camera.intel.intel.intel.cclicent"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Try to return false or different keycode, for example "enter"

Comment: Volume toolbar shows up on my phone for onKeyDown, not onKeyUp.